# CSS resize a block so it fills the void spaces

Tags: html, css

Html code

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="monstyle.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="section1">

        </section>

        <section id="section2">

        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

css code

---

```
#section1 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
#section2 {
    height:100px;
    width: 40;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My question is is there a "pure CSS" way to make sure that the "section2"'s width will be increased to fit te stcreen when reducing the screen under 800px?
If yes, how?

Comment: '"section2"'s width will be increased ' - you probably mean "decreased"?

Comment: you mean height: 100% ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, 1st section use float:left and 2nd set margin-left:<width of 1st section>. This should solve your issue

Comment: ...also `width:40` is invalid.

Comment: Possibly a typo in your css code but `width: 40;` has no unit and is therefore pretty meaningless. Do you mean `width: 40%;`?

Comment: @nicael I really mean increased.When I reduce the browser width with the mouse, it reaches a point where each section cant be reduced anymore, so at that point the section2 will go below section1`, leaving an empty space next to section1. My question is how can I detect that change, and increase the size of both sections.

Comment: @BrettJephson it is in deed width: 40%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

```css
body {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow multiple lines */
}
#section1 {
  flex: 1 400px; /* Start at 400px, grow to fill available space */
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#section2 {
  flex: 1 400px; /* Start at 400px, grow to fill available space */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1"></section>
<section id="section2"></section>
```

Comment: the CSS code above works fine

Answer (score 3):

You can handle this by [using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). I recommend to follow a [mobile first](http://zurb.com/word/mobile-first) approach, something like this:

```
#section2 {
    width: 100%; /* this might not be necessary */
}    

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #section2 {
        width: 40%;
        min-width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you put the section2's width 100%, it will stay on it own line from the biginning, 
But I am looking for the way to dynamically increase width from 40% to 100% after reducing the browser screen's width up to say 800px